# How to Use openssl with springboot/mySql and dropzonejs

Tags: spring-boot, encryption, openssl, dropzone.js

excuse me for my englishe. In the meantime I develop an electronic document management with springboot in backend and a angular2 in front. until now the download and the stokage in my database pass very well by against the part encryption and decryption with openssl implementer in my springboot does not work.

**Class FileUpload**

```
@Table(name = "table_doc")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Document(indexName = "tabledoc", type = "tabledoc")
public class FileUpload implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String filename;

@Lob
private byte[] file;

private String mimeType;

private Long size;

public FileUpload(String filename, byte[] file, String mimeType, Long size) {
    super();
    this.filename = filename;
    this.file = file;
    this.mimeType = mimeType;
    this.size = size;
}
public FileUpload() {
    super();
}
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
}
public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}
public byte[] getFile() {
    return file;
}
public void setFile(byte[] file) {
    this.file = file;
}
public String getMimeType() {
    return mimeType;
}
public void setMimeType(String mimeType) {
    this.mimeType = mimeType;
}
public Long getSize() {
    return size;
}
public void setSize(Long size) {
    this.size = size;
}
}
```

**Class FileController:**

```
  @RequestMapping(value ="/uploadLobCrypt",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ResponseEntity <String> fileCrypt(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,MultipartFile multiPartFile) throws IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException  {
    Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
    String uploadedFile = itr.next();
    MultipartFile file = request.getFile(uploadedFile); 
    String mimeType = file.getContentType();
    String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    Long size = file.getSize();
    FileUpload fileCrypte = new FileUpload(filename, bytes, mimeType,size);
    fileLobService.fileCrypt(multiPartFile,fileCrypte);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("{}", HttpStatus.OK);     
}
```

**Class FileLobService**

```
@Service("fileLobService")
@Transactional
public class FileLobService {
@Autowired
FileUploadRepository fileUploadRepository;

// Retrouver un fichier
public FileUpload findByFilename(String filename) {
    return fileUploadRepository.findByFilename(filename);
}

public FileUpload findById(Long id) {
    return fileUploadRepository.findById(id);
}

public Long deleteFileById(Long id) {
    return fileUploadRepository.deleteFileById(id);
}

public String deleteFileByFilename(String filename) {
    return fileUploadRepository.deleteFileByFilename(filename);
}

public void File(File file) {
    fileUploadRepository.File(file);
}

// Upload the file
public void uploadFile(FileUpload fileName) {

    fileUploadRepository.saveAndFlush(fileName);
}

public void fileCrypt(MultipartFile multiPartFile, FileUpload fileCrypte)
        throws IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException {

    // ecriture clee public et public dans un path
    String publicKeyPath = "C:\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\public.der";
    String privateKeyPath = "C:\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\private.pk8";

    fileCrypte.setFile(multiPartFile.getBytes());
    fileCrypte.setFilename(multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    fileCrypte.setMimeType(multiPartFile.getContentType());
    fileCrypte.setSize(multiPartFile.getSize());
    File file = new File(multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename());
    multiPartFile.transferTo(file);
    byte[] dataBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
    Cryptage cryptage = new Cryptage();
    byte[] encryptedBytes = cryptage.encryptFile(dataBytes, publicKeyPath);
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, encryptedBytes);

    fileUploadRepository.saveCryptedFile(file);
}
}
```

**Class FileUploadRepository**

```
 public interface FileUploadRepository extends JpaRepository<FileUpload, Long> {
FileUpload findByFilename(String filename);

FileUpload findById(Long id);

Long deleteFileById(Long id);

String deleteFileByFilename(String filename);

void File(File file);

void saveCryptedFile(java.io.File file);
}
```

Now, when I start up the server, I get the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No 
property saveCryptedFile found for type FileUpload!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>
(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at 
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) 
~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at 
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) 
~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272) 
~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) 
~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>
(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

do you have any idea about using Openssl in SpringBoot to encrypt download files with dropzonejs before being stored in my Mysql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was just needed Return the contents of the file as an array of bytes. with the encryption class

Class FileController while be changed:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/uploadLobCrypt",method = RequestMethod.POST)

public ResponseEntity <String> fileCrypt(MultipartFile multiPartFile,MultipartHttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException  {

    fileLobService.fileCrypt(multiPartFile, request);

    return new ResponseEntity<String>("{}", HttpStatus.OK);     
}
```

Class FileLobService

```
public void fileCrypt(MultipartFile 
multiPartFile,MultipartHttpServletRequest 
request) throws IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
NoSuchPaddingException,IllegalBlockSizeException, 
BadPaddingException,InvalidKeySpecException {

    // ecriture clee public et public dans un path
    String publicKeyPath = "C:\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\public.der";
    //String privateKeyPath = "C:\\OpenSSL-Win64\\bin\\private.pk8";

    Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();

    String uploadedFile = itr.next();
    MultipartFile file = request.getFile(uploadedFile); 

    String mimeType = file.getContentType();
    String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    Long size = file.getSize();

    Cryptage cryptage = new Cryptage();
    byte[] encryptedBytes = cryptage.encryptFile(bytes, publicKeyPath);

    FileUpload fileUploaded = new FileUpload(filename, encryptedBytes, mimeType,size);

    fileUploadRepository.saveAndFlush(fileUploaded);

}
```

note : it is useful just for small files for a large file we must use a SHA-256 message-digest algorithm or more